# Combine row value to columns

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a data like this

```
DUMP A;
(2013-11, a)
(2013-11, b)
(2013-11, c)
(2013-11, d)
(2013-12, e)
```

and I would like to merge row with the same key to be like this (my desired output):

```
(2013-11, a, b, c, d)
(2013-12, e)
```

How can I achieve this using Pig Latin alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`GROUP`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#GROUP) operator.  You can use it like:

```
-- A is your sample.

B = GROUP A BY $0 ;
DUMP B ;
-- (2013-11, {(a), (b), (c), (d)})
-- (2013-12, {(e)}
```

Note, there is no guarantee the bag will have the values in alphabetical (or any) order.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using `GROUP` operator but I am not sure how to reference the column within the table.

Comment: In this case, the output for `a b c d` is bag. How can I flatten this? I tried `C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(A);` but that doesn't give me the needed result as above.

Comment: By flatten do you mean turn it into a tuple?  If you are not 100% sure how many columns there will be then you need to use a bag.  Depending on why you need to do this there is probably a better solution.

Comment: Yes, just like my desired output above. After messing around, I figured the way I approached the problem was wrong and it won't achieve my end result. So I need to resort to doing it another way. I'm trying to group log messages by year/month (key) and have each column contains the number of log for each host. Still couldn't figure it out how to get it done using Pig.

Comment: Feel free to open another question about that with what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mr2ert, here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114798/aggregate-row-value-into-columns